# Algolia PHP API not returning all records

Tags: php, algolia

I am using Algolia search services in PHP, my API  call is not returning all records. Any solution? maximum records returned are 1000, but total number of records are much more than 1000.

Comment: Records of what? Logs or what?

Please explain further and show us your code, I searched their docs and they say that they limit the response to 1000 registries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Search() function returns maximum 1000 records, please use browseAll(). 
Ref :[Browseall()](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#browse-all-index-content)

Comment: got it. Thanks alot